# create RPM with python script and protoc-generated modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, protocol-buffers, rpm, rpm-spec

I have `python` script which also imports `protoc`-generated modules (protobuf and grpc). I would like to package this in `rpm`. Previously I used to write a `spec` file defining rpm, its contents, compile/link flags (if building from c/c++ sources), post/postun phases if any and so on.

What would be the correct way to create rpm for python script + generated python modules. I know that there is `distutils` python module, and people normally write their own `setup.py` script, and then do `python setup.py bdist_rpm`. However I'm not sure how I can plug-in the protobuf generation phase.

I'd appreciate helpful suggestions!